# How to split rows by value and count them?

Tags: sql, count

I am having one table TEMP(FILEID, WORD, ORG) with every word from a collection of files attached with fileID (FILEID), and the organization (ORG) that published the file.

[image]
Now I want to group by words and see how many times they show under one ORG('DMS') and how many times it shows in other ORG ('NONDMS') files. It should looks like this:

```
WORD   DMS(count) NOTDMS(count)
health   118          32
```

This is my current code. not sure if it is even the right thing to do.

```
CREATE Table  DMSCOUNT(WORD varchar(200), DMSTotal int, NOTDMSTotal int)
INSERT INTO DMSCOUNT
SELECT WORD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG != 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TEMP
GROUP BY WORD;
```

This is the error message I am getting:

`Error at Command Line:2 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE Table  DMSCOUNT(WORD varchar(200), DMSTotal int, NOTDMSTotal int)

INSERT INTO DMSCOUNT
SELECT Word,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG != 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM temp
GROUP BY Word
```

Comment: No, it's not. The error line is `COUNT(CASE WHEN ORG!= 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NonDMSTotal`, the message is `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"`.

Comment: I donno why it's not working. Attached the screenshot to my post above.

Comment: remove semicolon at end of INSERT INTO statement and execute ..check if it works

Comment: The after SELECTI part is working now, still can not create the table. Here is the error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 11`. The error is in line '       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 END),'.

Comment: Do I need a `as` statement after the `create table` statement?

Comment: You have not put comma after first SUM() statement..this is throwing error

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , SUM(CASE WHEN ORG != 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: I tried both with and without comma. The piece after `SELECT` is working now, but can not create the table.

Comment: remove all the queries except above posted one .. also put semicolon at end of create table dmstotal statement only ..and then execute

Comment: Do I need to indent my code like this link shows? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm